# finish() isnt destroying the activity

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, firebase-realtime-database

Im new to firebase finish() dont kill my signup activity but it keeps going on in the background. and keeps putting data to database continously. 
i dont know what to do.

Signup.java  code snippet

```
    final Button signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);
    final EditText name, phno, password;
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_name);
    phno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_phno);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sign_up_pass);
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference table_user = database.getReference("User");
    signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ProgressDialog mdialog= new ProgressDialog(Signup.this);
            mdialog.setMessage("Please wait");
            mdialog.show();
            table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                        if(dataSnapshot.child(phno.getText().toString()).exists())
                        {
                            mdialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"Phone No. Already Registered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mdialog.dismiss();
                            User user = new User(name.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
                            table_user.child(phno.getText().toString()).setValue(user);
                            Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Sign Up Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
```

//redirects to mainActivity.java but data insersion continues code is completely written with perfectly closed paranthesis

User.java

```
public class User {
private String Name;
private String Password;

public User(String y,String x) {
    Name=y;
    Password=x;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return Password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    Password = password;
}
}
```

activity_signup.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_name"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_phno"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/sign_up_name"
        android:hint="Phone No."/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_pass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/sign_up_phno"
        android:hint="password"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_below="@id/sign_up_pass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/signup"
        android:text="Sign up"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

is there any way to fix this. finish ()

Comment: you are not directing to main activity if sign up is successful in your code.

Comment: You need to removeListener from firebase before finishing the activity .

Comment: did you debug your code which is inserting or not in else condition.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your activity will remain in memory even after finish() because Firebase event listeners needed to be explicitly removed.

You are adding

```
table_user.addValueEventListener(<your_listener>);
```

Before `finish()`, you should

```
table_user.removeEventListener(<your_listener>);
```

to clear the reference to the activity. You might have to create a private EventListener (not sure about the exact class name) object so that you can reference it later when removing.

Comment: i used table_user.removeEventListener(this); new to android ... "this " keyword worked for me  thanks krishna .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go back to MainActivity then you need to do this instead of finish():

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Because you cant directly finishes activity in android you have to tell it before destroying it that where to head from there.

Comment: Buddy I updated my answer , please check now. This will work. And please dont forget to mark this post as answer if this works for you :)

Comment: i tried it but the best answer was given by Krishnabhadra. a little bit of modification made the code work.